# Entity Framework connect to Oracle: ODP for .NET "does not support time"

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework

I have an Entity framework set up where I have a remote Oracle Server that I've configured through the connection string and I'm not running some unit Tests to confirm connection. I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

I'm getting the error:
**System.NotSupportedException: Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time**.

I can't find anyone getting this error before. 
I was thinking my tables in my Oracle DB might have many mentions to time, but they only have DATE. 
I have to do it this way, I won't be able to just access the DB a different way for this project.

What could be causing this error? How can I remedy it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have dates stored as '2015-06-30 08:13:24' this is a date time literal.

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/featLINQ.htm) states

> ODP.NET does not support Time literals and canonical functions related
>   to the Time type.

Look through your tables for dates stored as VARCHAR2.  I can say from experience that EF4 at a minimum has no problem with DATE or TIMESTAMP fields so the problem you have has to be somewhere else.

I would not normally consider storing a time in a CHAR variable.  In EF I have frequently had to CAST values to a more acceptable datatype.  As an example:

```
select CAST(your_date ||' '||your_time AS DATE) AS your_field from your_table;
```

You may be running into an issue with using Oracle keywords in your column names.
Here is a [list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) of Oracle keywords and reserved words.  TIME is included in the list. If you have column names called TIME this could be your problem.

Try making a view of the table where you rename TIME to TIME_T or something.

Comment: so, you think the problem is a date/time stored as a VARCHAR2?  If so, I can look in to that and report back my results... I have a TIME field, things like 05:30, as a char(5)

Comment: I get this error even when pinging a table with no time/date in it. The error shows seemingly because there is time literals in the DB. So I'm not sure casting would work