# "Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time" error in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

We have migrated a database from SQL Server to Oracle. Our application should run on both databases. So we have used Entity Framework 6. While inserting a record via EF6, we are getting this exception:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Here is the code that is raising this exception:

```cs
public class ActivityLog
{
    public DateTime TimeAccessed { get; set; }
}

NeoSampleDBEntities context = new NeoSampleDBEntities();
context.ActivityLogs.Add(_activityLog);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I believe that the source of this exception is a date/time string that looks like this:

```
11/07/2014 12:45:12
```

Oracle offers a function named `to_date()`. Using this function, we can insert a date with a time. But how can we do this from EF6? I don't want to make changes in all our models as we have to run the application on both SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: [Check this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31189941/2224701).

Comment: What is the type of the property in instance `_activityLog` that has the date time? Is it a string? Please provide the relevant model code.